# GDB and Fortran modules

Tags: fortran, gdb

I have the following Fortran 95 code:

```
MODULE ISSUE
    IMPLICIT NONE
    CONTAINS
    SUBROUTINE PROBLEM(A)
        IMPLICIT NONE
        DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(:,:), INTENT(INOUT) :: A
        INTEGER :: i, n

        n = SIZE(A, 2)

        DO i = 1, n
            PRINT *, A(i, 1:n)
        ENDDO

    END SUBROUTINE PROBLEM
END MODULE ISSUE

PROGRAM TEST
    USE ISSUE
    IMPLICIT NONE
    DOUBLE PRECISION, DIMENSION(5, 5) :: A

    A = TRANSPOSE(RESHAPE((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, & 
                             6, 7, 8, 9, 0, &
                             1, 2, 3, 4, 5, &
                             6, 7, 8, 9, 0, &
                             1, 2, 3, 4, 5/), SHAPE(A)))
    CALL PROBLEM(A)
END PROGRAM TEST
```

And now I compile it using

```
gfortran -g -O0 problem.f95 -o problem
```

Then I run the program using GDB 7.7.1 and I set a breakpoint to line 11, (`DO i = 1, n`). After that, I print the first element of the matrix A. The output that I get is:

```
(gdb) break 11
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4008c5: file problem.f95, line 11.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path_to_problem_folder/problem 

Breakpoint 1, issue::problem (a=...) at problem.f95:11
warning: Source file is more recent than executable.
11              DO i = 1, n
(gdb) p A(1, 1)
$1 = 6.9533558074105031e-310
```

I expect the output **1**, but **6.9533558074105031e-310** is printed by gdb. Note that the subroutine `PROBLEM` prints all values correctly.

Why this happens and how can I print the value `A(1, 1)` correctly using GDB?

Comment: `warning: Source file is more recent than executable.` is generally not good. It means that executable has not been reloaded by the debugger or you compiled THEN changed things in your source.

Comment: That's because I idented it with VIM before copy-pasting. Note that StackOverflow requires an aditional TAB to detect it as a code. The problem persist after saving, recompiling and setting the debugger again.

Comment: I do not see this behavior using gdb 7.11.1 and gfortran 6.2.0 on a Debian sid x86_64 system. Perhaps you can be specific about which versions of gdb and gfortran you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my GDB version from 7.7.1 to 7.11.1 and the problem disappeared.